# If $x=9$, then can we write $\sqrt{x}=\pm3$ or only $\sqrt{x}=3$

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

If $x=9$, then can we write $\sqrt{x}=\pm3$ or only $\sqrt{x}=3$.

I am confused as square root always gives positive number.

But the irony is that if we have $a^2=9$, then we write $a=\pm3 \text {  where $a=\sqrt{a^2}$ }$

Comment: I'm confident this has been addressed before, so I'll find a proposed duplicate.  But the gist of the matter is that while $-3$ is "a square root" of $9$, the notation $\sqrt 9$ means the principal square root of $9$, namely $3$.  It is convenient to have this sort of meaning so that $\sqrt x$ has a functional dependence on $x$, at least for the simple case $x\ge 0$.

Comment: The square root function has a range of positive values only.

Comment: Regarding your "irony", if we have $a^2=9$ then we write the two solutions $a=\pm \sqrt 9 = \pm 3$.

Comment: @hardmath, but $a=\sqrt{a^2}$, how can $a$ be negative

Comment: Given $a^2=9$, there are two solutions to the quadratic equation.  The notation $\sqrt 9$ meaning the positive square root of $9$ makes the notation specific, and allows us to identify both distinct roots, $+\sqrt 9$ and $-\sqrt 9$.

Comment: ok, for $x=9$, should we write $\sqrt{x}=\pm3$ or $\sqrt{x}=3$

Comment: If $x=9$, then $\sqrt x = 3$.  Right?  Given a value of $x\ge 0$, there exists a unique positive square root of $x$, and that is what we mean by $\sqrt x$.  Also, the meaning of $\sqrt{a^2}$ is the same as $|a|$, if $a$ is a real number.

Comment: @user3290550: The equality $a=\sqrt{a^2}$ is only true if $a \ge 0$. In general, $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $x^2=9$ has two solutions namely $x=\sqrt 9=3$ and $x=-\sqrt 9 = -3$

When we write $x=\pm 3$ we mean that both $3$ and $-3$ are solutions and it does not mean that they are equal.

Thus we have $x=\pm \sqrt 9$ which means there are two solutions and they are opposite   to each other.

In general  for a real number $x$ we have $$\sqrt {x^2}= |x|$$  which results in $$-\sqrt {x^2}= -|x|$$

Answer (score 2):

The square root, as a function, is defined to give only the positive value, because functions are allowed to have a unique image for every element in the domain.

However, if you think of the square root as a relation (functions are relations with special constraints set on them), then you can *relate* an element to both "square roots"

Comment: see I am asking a very simple question if $a^2=9$, then we write $a=\pm3$, but $a=\sqrt{a^2}$, how can $a$ be negative if square root of a number is always positive.

Comment: it depends of what you want the square root to be, or what you call the square root of a number. As a function/map $sqrt:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R $ then you can only take a positive value, because of the definition of a function. However, that's not the same as asking for the solutions of $a^2 = 9$, because those solutions are based on the notion that the square root is a function and thus the mapping of an element is unique

Comment: in other words, the *function* $sqrt(x)$ is always positive, which is not the same as saying that THE square root (there is no "THE square root" because, except for 0, it's not unique) is always positive. There is a distinction between "the function that maps a positive integer to its positive square root" and "the relation that relates a positive integer with all of its square roots"

Comment: @user3290550: It is false that “$a=\sqrt{a^2}$” always holds. What we have is $\sqrt{a^2} = |a|$ (absolute value of $a$), so that your equation *only* holds if $a\geq 0$ to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

The square root is a *function*, so it only takes one value per input (the positive, by convention).
$$\sqrt{\cdot}: \mathbb{R}^+_0 \to \mathbb{R}_0^+ $$
$$x \mapsto \sqrt{x} $$
where $\sqrt{x}$ is the unique nonnegative real number such that $(\sqrt{x})^2 = x$.

It can also be proven that, if $a$ and $b$ are *nonnegative*, it holds that $a = b \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{a}=\sqrt{b}$. (Edit: This essentially means that the square root function is one-to-one.)

Solving these equations relies on this fact. The first one is straightforward: $x = 9 \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{x} = \sqrt{9} = 3$ (you cannot write $\sqrt{x} = - 3$, because by definition the square root only takes nonnegative values).

The second equation seems to contradict this, because of the two solutions, but if you look closely at what's happening, it becomes clearer:
$$a^2 = 9 \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{a^2} = \sqrt{9} \Leftrightarrow |a| = 3 \Leftrightarrow a = -3 \:\lor a=3$$.

The catch here is that, because of the nonnegative value condition, $\sqrt{x^2} = |x| \neq x$.
Note that the two solutions don't come from taking the *square root*, but actually from taking the *absolute value*!

Many teachers skip that intermediate step, so it ends up looking like the square root is the cause of the two solutions, even though it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that often $\sqrt{n}$ is meant as the positive root. As a result, it is very common to see the solutions to $x^2=n$ expressed as $x=\pm\sqrt{n}$ rather than $\pm x=\sqrt{n}$. While they are equivalent mathematically, the latte